# SAPUI5: SAP-Server sends no-cache, Appcache doesn't work

Tags: sapui5, html5-appcache, sap-erp, netweaver, sap-bsp

I'm developing a SAPUI5 application that needs to work offline. I'm using the Eclipse plugin provided by SAP to develop and upload the app to the SAP server (SAP ECC 6.0, Enhancement Package 7) as a BSP application.

In Chrome my appcache works fine on all platforms, yet it doesn't work in any other browser. I found out that the server sends "cache-control: no-cache, no-store" for my index.html file.

I tried to set the Browser-Cache to 1 day in the properties of index.html in se80 on the SAP server, but that didn't change anything. I googled a lot but just can't find out how to turn this off. Thank you so much.